# How to scroll to a specific item in QListView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5.4

I'm using PyQt5 and have a QListView in IconMode (with a custom delegate, think of a thumbnail viewer).
When I click on an item and use the cursor keys to navigate, everything is fine. However, when I select an item programmatically and press a cursor key afterwards, selection jumps to the first item. Also, listView.scrollTo(index) doesn't do anything. I'm at a total loss.....
In the function that selects an item, this is what I do:

```
listView.selectionModel().select(QtCore.QItemSelection(index, index), QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
listView.scrollTo(index)
listView.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

What happens is that the new item is selected (in my delegate's paint function, `option.state` has the `QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected` flag), but the view doesn't scroll to make it visible. The item also is "current" (`listView.currentIndex()` returns the new index).
When I press the "down" cursor key, the first item in the view gets selected and current, and the view scrolls to the first item.
BTW, if I omit the call to `selectionModel().select(...)`, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Is the item visible in the view after `scrollTo` call? Is it selected (usually indicated by background) and is it current (usually indicated by dotted frame) correctly? Which key do you press after that?

Answer (score 2):

I came across much the same problem using C++ on Qt 5.15.6. I'm using a QListView with two columns, of which only one is displayed (the other column is the index key from a database: I need to keep it so that I can search the listview for a specific id, so that I can select it from the program.

I obtain a QModelIndex from QAbstractItemModel::match(), but using that to create the QItemSelection didn't work. Then I realised that QItemSelection takes two arguments: top-left and bottom-right, and I had no idea which column the QModelIndex I'd obtained referred to. So, just to be on the safe side, I created two more QModelIndexes using siblingAtColumn(0) and siblingAtColumn(1).

Using those in the QItemSelection constructor got the appropriate item selected -- but we still didn't scroll to it. Then I realised that the QModelIndex I was using for that function probably referred to column 0 -- which isn't displayed in my implementation. Changing it to the QModelIndex for column 1 allowed it to scroll correctly.

Perhaps I've given you some ideas that may answer your question. In particular, check that the first argument to scrollTo() refers to the column that you're displaying. If you're displaying more than one column, point to the left-hand one (I'm guessing here, of course).

This is the resulting code:

```
Ui::MainWindow *pMainWindow = MainWindow::getMainWindowPtr();
    pMainWindow->itemsListView->setCurrentIndex(itemIndex);

    QModelIndex itemIndex0 = itemIndex.siblingAtColumn(0);
    QModelIndex itemIndex1 = itemIndex.siblingAtColumn(1);
    QItemSelection *selection = new QItemSelection(itemIndex0, itemIndex1);
    QItemSelectionModel *itemSelectionModel = pMainWindow->itemsListView->selectionModel();
    itemSelectionModel->select(*selection, QItemSelectionModel::SelectCurrent);

    pMainWindow->itemsListView->scrollTo(itemIndex1, QAbstractItemView::EnsureVisible);
```

Comment: The question is in Python. Can you convert your answer to Python for those of us that don't know C++?